# Take a string data format and covert while copying

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to pull a date in `CYYMMDD` Text format into `DD/MM/YYYY` Date format

I think I'm missing a step here as I'm not getting the prompts when typing in ".Formula" etc

I'm also sure there's a better way to do this without pasting the value in first

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("SALEREP17")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

With ws.Range("B" & lastRow)
    .Copy Destination:=Worksheets("PAGE 4-COMMERCIALS").Cells(17, 3)
End With

Set ws = Worksheets("PAGE 4-COMMERCIALS")

With Cells(17, 2)
    .Formula = "=RIGHT(RC[1],2)&""/""&MID(RC[1],4,2)&""/20""&MID(RC[1],2,2)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

[image]

[image]

So what this done is pulls the bottom row from the "date last changed" from our ODBC connection. It then pastes into the report tab and converts it into a date and removes the formula

Then I would just go on to delete the text in `(17, 3)` but there must be a better way than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, c As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("SALEREP17")
With ws
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set c = ws.Cells(lastRow, 2)
    Worksheets("PAGE 4-COMMERCIALS").Cells(17, 3).Value = DateSerial(Mid(c, 2, 2), Mid(c, 4, 2), Mid(c, 6, 2))
End With
```

Note: the `(1000 * Left(c, 1))` part isn't strictly necessary, unless you want the code to work for several hundred years..

Comment: I'd hope our business changes software by then! I'm getting an Error 1004 on the `Worksheets ("PAGE....` line(s), any idea why?

Comment: Assuming that's the name of worksheet, with no typos.. is is possible the line hasn't copied correctly? I'll edit the code in my answer to ensure the code flows correctly, although it's slightly harder to read.

Comment: Coped worksheet names direct from the workbook and used your new line - still the same error. Is `For Each c In` meant to give me multiple lines of data - because I only need the bottom-most text-date to be sent to one specific cell for conversion to date-date - is that why?

Comment: Also, I've just noticed your sample data isn't *actually* `CYYMMDD` - it's `CYYMDD` - I hope that's not the case in your real data?

Comment: Ah. I assumed you wanted them all. I'll alter the answer.

Comment: My sample data is CYYMMDD (at least in my knowledge of it). It's the 1st century, 16th year, 04th month and 01st day - 1-16-04-01 - maybe I'm not using the right "naming" for SO, I'm just using what the iSeries gives me

Comment: Okay, I've removed the century part, as I think that was causing the issue with `1`. Try using the code as is now.

Comment: Perfect - I've amended it to the above (changing cells to `17, 2` as I was using `17, 3` as a placeholder. Works perfectly now

Answer (score 1):

`range("a1").value=dateserial(mid(x,2,2),mid(x,4,2),mid(x,6,2))` where x is your date.

Comment: Okay so `Mid` etc. uses String but if I declare `lastDate As String` and call the value of `"B" & lastRow` I get a type mismatch

Comment: What has `lastRow` got to do with this part?

Comment: `lastDate` sorry - I added this variable so I can pull the text value of the last date every time `lastDate = ws.Range("B" & lastRow)`

Comment: That should work.  You have `Dim LastDate as string:LastDate=ws.range("B" & lastRow)` and `LastRow` has a value?

Comment: Exactly that - I've set `Range("B17") = LastDate` and get the text value, but putting it into `DateSerial` doesn't work